# RelativeLayout: how to delete border around second layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an `xml` file which contains two `RelativeLayout`s. The trouble is that the second `Relativelayout` does not go up to the display limit. It looks like a border around the layout.

How can I display the second layer also on the border of the display?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="newservice"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_newservice">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/viewmap"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your

**android:paddingXXX** from parent `RelatvieLayout`

that is making issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line on the top layout:

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

You are putting a padding on the top, so the second layout will not fill the first like you want.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="newservice"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_newservice">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/viewmap"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Try this